# Unable to read array values in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

How to Read and write array Output from activity(row outputs) as input to  foreach loop in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Hi@Being Real, you want to pass array variable to forEach in ADF ?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT yes I want to access the previous activity output( i made o/p as an array) and do manipulations inside foreach loop How can I aceess these values in foreach loop

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT
Thank yu,How can i set the value of new_values_array in variables inside foreach loop Eg(1,2,3,4) i need to set v=1,q=2,etc like that

Comment: You just use the `@item()` syntax within the For Each activity.  I would need to see some sample data and expected results for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i set the value of new_values_array in variables inside foreach loop Eg(1,2,3,4) i need to set v=1,q=2,etc like that

To get the Result array like a=1,b=2, you need another array for the letters.

Here I am using 3 arrays and generating the result array with append activity.

`numbers_array` -> for the numbers `[1,2,3,4]`(This is your output array from previous activity).

`letters` -> for the letters `["a","b","c","d"]`.

`index_array` -> extra array of indexes for using two arrays inside Foreach using their indexes. `@range(0,length(variables('numbers_array')))` results `[0,1,2,3]`.

`new_values_array` -> Result array in append activity inside ForEach.

**numbers_array:**

[image]

**letters array:**

[image]

**index_array:**

[image]

In ForEach, **check the Sequential** and **give the index_array** as `@variables('index_array')` because **by using this array we are getting the values of multiple arrays inside ForEach**.

[image]

**Inside ForEach use append** and give the below dynamic content for `new_values_array`.

```
@concat(variables('letters')[item()],'=',variables('numbers_array')[item()])
```

[image]

Result in another array(**Optional step, only for showing output here):**

[image]

**Output after pipeline execution:**

[image]