# Copying CSV from adls to adls not working in adf pipeline

Tags: foreach, copy, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

[image: sink of my copy activity]

[image: source of my copy activity]

I want to copy the CSV files present in adlsfolder called source to another adls folder called destination through adf pipeline copy activity.

1st activity = *GetMetadata*
to get all the files from the source folder.

2nd activity = *foreach*
to loop through the files

Inside 2nd activity= *copy activity* to copy from source to destination.

My source dataset is correctly pointing to the source folder and same with the output dataset.

I'm using the same filenames in destination as present in source adls.

Even though there's no error after running the pipeline, but the data present in source files is not present in the destination files.

The filenames are coming correctly in the destination as in the source, which is want I wanted .

But the data is incorrect.

For example let's say I have 5 files in source as follows:

- Classone_00000.csv
- Classone_00001.csv
- Classtwo_00000.csv
- Classtwo_00001.csv
- Classtwo_00003.csv

I'm using partition and have mentioned 5 rows per file.

In the destination I will still have all the 5 files with the same filename , but the data is incorrect. In my case classone_00000.csv data would be present in all the 4 other files and if there were 5 rows in source file, there would be only 4 files in my destination files.

I'm not able to figure out why that's happening.

I have tried making the foreach sequential and not sequential, but nothing seems to be working.

I just want the data present in adls source folder to get copied exactly to the adls destination folder.

Comment: Can you provide your copy activity source and sink configurations for better understanding?

Comment: I've added the pictures of my source and sink in the post, pleas look into it. I'm very new here so let me know if you're not able to see the pictures or if you need any other input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, the copy activity will give all the source files in every iteration and for every target file the last source file data will be overwritten into target file. This might be the reason for your incorrect data.

To achieve your requirement, there is no need to use loop. You can do the same with a single copy activity in the pipeline.

Give the path till the container in the source dataset and **give your wildcard path in the copy activity** source dataset.

[image]

In the target dataset, give the path till your target folder location. Don't give any filepath.

[image]

Give this to the copy activity sink.

[image]

Execute the pipeline and all files in the source location will be copied to the target location.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is working, But what changes do I have to make if I want to rename the files in my sink???

Comment: @Bindu, Then use the same loop approach. But Use Dataset parameters for both source and sink datasets. Give the particular filename for every file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong , so in both source and sink instead of using item(). In the filename of the dataset, I should create a parameter for the filename, say for ex: fl_name_sink and fl_name_source and it's dynamic content would be item().name

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood your question. Currently ADF can't rename the files. The approach would be create new file with new name for every file and delete the old file in the same iteration. Use dataset parameters for both source and sink filenames. Give `@item().name` for the source and for the sink, you need to give the required name for that file like if you want to add any string to the current filenames for example `@concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],'_new','.csv')`.

Comment: If you have the correct order of renames array. Then you need to use a different approach. To iterate multiple arrays inside the same for loop, you need to pass an index array to the ForEach and use that index(`@item()`) for Get meta data array and renames array. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964674/unable-to-read-array-values-in-azure-data-factory/72965185#72965185) to know about how to iterate mutliple arrays inside same for loop by passing an index array

Comment: Yeah okay, thank you for your help.